# How to save vector data of structs to a file then load/retrieve it?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, load, save

I'm working on making a 'simple' Console-based game in C++ (VS 2012) and I've been able to get the data (xpos etc) for the 'Player' class to save (by putting the data into a struct then saving the struct). However with the Enemies and Holes classes, I can't quite save the data. These two classes are used as vectors, and have their own structs.

SaveGameData struct: This one stores basic data about the game (how many 'active' zombies there are, the player's position, how many holes there are, size of the map and the difficulty level.

ZombieData struct: Stores the X and Y position of each zombie

HoleData struct: Stores the X and Y position of each Hole (I could probably use ZombieData struct for this and will likely merge them later on, but ignore that for now :P )

My plan was to access the data for each existing zombie through it's class, then using get/set methods in each class, get the relevant data from the class vectors, and store it in the structs. This then gets written to a .dat file in binary format.

I can't really tell if this works because...well..I can't open the file. But when I try to load it, the player moves to his/her 'saved' position. because the Holes do not move, I cannot tell if they save properly. But the zombies don't save/load properly. Sometimes, the zombies will double up (IE if one died, when loading, it will stick the 'dead one' onto the side of one of the existing zombies) or they simply do not revert back totheir saved position.

What I have noticed with Holes is that there is one (or more - unable to tell) that spawns in the top left corner of the map (the border where nothing can get to) and I've no idea why.

I tried deleting them all upon load, starting a blank slate so to speak, then loading the data from the file(s), but that does not work. And I can't figure out what is wrong.

Structs:

```
struct SaveGameData{

    int playerX;
    int playerY;
    int zombieCount;
    int holeCount;
    int sizeOfMap;
    int difficultyLevel;

};

struct ZombieData{

    int zombieX;
    int zombieY;

};

struct HoleData{

    int holeX;
    int holeY;

};


void saveGameState(SaveGameData&, vector<ZombieData>&, vector<HoleData>&, vector<Holes>&, vector<Enemies>&, int, int, int, int);
void loadGameState(SaveGameData&, fstream &, Player&, vector<Enemies>&, vector<Holes>&, vector<ZombieData>&, vector<HoleData>&);
```

Main Game (While) loop;

```
decision = ' ';

            cycle = cycle + 1;

            hSize = holes.size();
            eSize = zombies.size();
            pX = human.getX();
            pY = human.getY();
            pAlive = human.getAlive();  

            if(eSize == 0 || !pAlive)
            {
                loadFile.open("saveDataFile.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
                if(loadFile)
                {
                    HNDCONSOLE_H gotoxy(10,10);
                    HNDCONSOLE_H setrgb(0);
                    cout << "Would you like to load from the save point? Y/N" << endl;
                    decision = _getch();
                    if(decision == 'y' || decision == 'Y'){
                        loadGameState(saveGame, loadFile, human, zombies, holes, zombieSaveData, holeSaveData);
                        gameover = false;
                    }
                    else
                        gameover = true;
                }
                else                    
                    gameover = true;
            }


            PLAYER_H human.movePlayer(mapSize, pAlive); 
            HOLES_H myHoles.drawHole(holes);
            ENEMIES_H myZombies.enemyMove(zombies, level, mapSize);
            PLAYER_H human.playerCollision(zombies, holes);
            ENEMIES_H myZombies.zombieCollide(zombies, holes);
            ENEMIES_H myZombies.zombieDelete(zombies);

            if(cycle % 15 == 0){
                HNDCONSOLE_H gotoxy(35,10);
                cout << "Would you like to save?" << endl;
                HNDCONSOLE_H gotoxy(38,11);
                cout << "Y/N" << endl;
                HNDCONSOLE_H gotoxy(35,12);
                decision = _getch();

                if(decision == 'y' || decision == 'Y')
                {
                    saveGameState(saveGame, zombieSaveData, holeSaveData, holes, zombies, mapSize, difficulty, pX, pY);
                    cout << "Game saved. Carry one playing as normal";
                }
                else
                    cout << "Your decision was No. Carry on playing as normal";
            }
```

Save/Load Functions;

```
void saveGameState(SaveGameData& newSave, vector<ZombieData>& newZombieData, vector<HoleData>& newHoleData, vector<Holes>& hole, vector<Enemies>& zombie, int mapSize, int difficulty, int pX, int pY){

    fstream saveFile, zombieFile, holeFile;


    saveFile.open("saveDataFile.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);

    newSave.sizeOfMap = mapSize;
    newSave.difficultyLevel = difficulty;
    newSave.playerX = pX;
    newSave.playerY = pY;
    newSave.holeCount = hole.size();
    newSave.zombieCount = zombie.size();

    saveFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&newSave), sizeof(newSave));

    saveFile.close();


    zombieFile.open("saveZombieFile.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    for(int i = 0; i < newSave.zombieCount; i++)
    {
        newZombieData.push_back(ZombieData());
        newZombieData[i].zombieX = zombie[i].getX();
        newZombieData[i].zombieY = zombie[i].getY();
    }
    zombieFile.close();


    holeFile.open("saveZombieFile.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    for(int i = 0; i < newSave.holeCount; i++)
    {
        newHoleData.push_back(HoleData());
        newHoleData[i].holeX = hole[i].getX();
        newHoleData[i].holeY = hole[i].getY();
    }
    holeFile.close();

}
```

Things that name I forgot (I added it so you can see the variable types involved easier?)

```
void loadGameState(SaveGameData& newSave, fstream &loadFile, Player& newHuman, vector<Enemies>& newZombie, vector<Holes>& newHole, vector<ZombieData>& newZombieData, vector<HoleData>& newHoleData){


    loadFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&newSave), sizeof(newSave));

    int zombieCount = newSave.zombieCount;
    int holeCount = newSave.holeCount;

    newHuman.setX(newSave.playerX);
    newHuman.setY(newSave.playerY);

    for(int k = 0; k < newZombie.size(); k++)
        newZombie.erase(newZombie.begin() + k);

    for(int l = 0; l < newHole.size(); l++)     
        newHole.erase(newHole.begin() + l);

    for(int i = 0; i < zombieCount; i++)
    {
        newZombie.push_back(Enemies());
        newZombie[i].setX(newZombieData[i].zombieX);
        newZombie[i].setY(newZombieData[i].zombieY);
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < holeCount; j++)
    {
        newHole.push_back(Holes());
        newHole[j].setX(newHoleData[j].holeX);
        newHole[j].setY(newHoleData[j].holeY);
    }

    loadFile.close();
}
```

Comment: So where do you actually write the information about zombies to the file?

Comment: Why didn't you unit test file saving/retrieval first to make sure it works before applying it to the larger program?  You have posted a lot of code that has nothing to do with your problem.  A struct (or set of structs) and a 3 or 4 line program to test the file saving and retrieval is all that is needed.

Comment: Wait the format for this seems to have messed up a tad.

@AlexSee: the data gets written in the `saveGameState` function below the heading 'Save/load Functions'

@PaulMcKenzie: I'm sorry whats a Unit-Test? (I've never heard of that - yet - haha. Probably a silly question :/ )

Comment: You should write a small main() program that does nothing else except save and load your data.  Nothing more, nothing less.  Once you have that working, then and only then do you move that working code into the larger program.  That in essence is unit testing.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing

Comment: Well you also want the ability to test for state equality.  I would also have a state duplication (maybe copy construct) method so I can test equality without serialization.  Also ways to swap out what state you display for more sanity checks.

Comment: @NeoKuro I mean, where is the line where the data get actually written to zombieFile? I can't see it.